# How to create a directional vector that moves a certain entity to a certain location

Tags: c++, vector, game-physics, stdvector, game-development

**General explanation:**

I'm building this game where I have to move a certain ball to a location depending on where the rotation is facing, basically
there are a bunch of blocks in the background and some barriers and there's a collision detection algorithm implemented so the ball returns to its original position upon collision

**Problem:**

I need to move the ball with a directional vector but I don't know how to do that, I've been holding the spacebar to move but I want it so it moves on its own upon clicking the spacebar *with* a directional vector

**Goal:**

once again, I want it to move on its own with a directional vector when the spacebar is clicked. Upon collision, I want the ball to reflect on the opposite angle, imagine you throw a ball at a wall, and then it goes to the other wall and then eventually stops, how would that be possible?

**Code:**

```
void collisionDetection(Entity* ball, Entity* block)
{
    //Collision detection function
    //Radius
    const float blockRadius = 5.0f;
    const float ballRadius = 2.0f;

        //block coords
        float xBlock = block.GetX;
        float yBlock = block.GetY;
        float zBlock = block.GetZ;

        //ball coords
        float xBall, yBall, zBall;
        xBall = ball.GetX;
        yBall = ball.GetY;
        zBall = ball.GetZ;

        //max boundaries + radius
        float xMax, yMax, zMax;
        xMax = xBall + blockRadius + ballRadius;
        yMax = yBall + blockRadius + ballRadius;
        zMax = zBall + blockRadius + ballRadius;

        //min boundaries - radius
        float xMin, yMin, zMin;
        xMin = xBall - blockRadius - ballRadius;
        yMin = yBall - blockRadius - ballRadius;
        zMin = zBall - blockRadius - ballRadius;


        //main process
if ((xBlock > xMin && xBlock < xMax) && (yBlock > yMin && yBlock < yMax) && (zBlock > zMin && zBlock < zMax))
        {
            ball.SetPosition(0, 2, 0);
        }
    }

void main()
{
//Blocks
std::vector<Entity*> blocks; //Declaring a vector for the blocks
float xPosition = -55; //Initial position of the wall of blocks

//For loop that automatically renders the blocks & puts them in place with proper distance between them
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        blocks.push_back(blockEntity.Spawn(xPosition, 5, 120));
        xPosition += 12; //incrementing the value of x so the blocks generate with proper distance between them
    }

ballEntity.Spawn(0, 2, 0);

if(Key_(Space).isHeld)
{
ball.MoveZ(0.3f);
}

//Detecting the collision
for (Entity* block : blocks)
        {
                collisionDetection(ball, block);
        }
}
```

Comment: Your problem has two parts, plus a third part from your goal. **1)** "move the ball with a directional vector"; **2)** respond to the spacebar; **3)** respond to collisions. You should work on one part at a time. One possibility is to (try to) have the ball move all the time regardless of input. Once you have that down, you can proceed to either adding a triggering mechanism based on user input or handling collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Newtonian equations?
The entity has Velocity, Acceleration (with a -9.81 m/s^2 in y dir). Once you have the equation in place, you can calculate individual components (x,y, and z) for the velocity and update each component accordingly (simple trigonometry calculations).

Once you click the spacebar all you need to do apply acceleration and update the values. You need to keep updating the values in your Draw()/Update() functions that are called to match the FPS.
So you need a `main` loop that calls Draw() or Update() function several times in a second. A generic template can be -

```
while(true) {
  // run at 120FPS, per cycle budget ~8.3ms
  long long start_time = getCurrentTimeNano();
  ReadInput();
  Update();
  DetectCollisions();
  Draw();
  long long budget_used = getCurrentTimeNano() - start_time;
  sleep(clamp(8300000LL - budget_used, 0LL, 8300000LL));
}
```

Upon detecting a collision and getting the point on the sphere where the collision happened, you can calculate a normal vector perpendicular to that point facing outwards. Now you can apply to do the same (calculate individual components and keep updating).

A better approach is to have a model matrix that will contain the translation, rotation information for an entity, a view matrix that will map those coordinates into camera view (between 1,-1), and finally a projection matrix (ortho/perspective).

If you want to understand the math a little bit better, you can check [this link](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the ball's position will be denoted by a 2D vector, denoted P.

```
P = [P1, P2]
```

To move this P in a 2D plane, you need a kind of push or force or whatever that changes your vector position and yields a new vector as a position:

```
P#1 = P#0 + Vchange
```

P#1: Position at T=1; P#0: Position at T=0.

Now

```
    // imagine your ball started with certain position
    if(Key_(Space).isClicked)
    {
       while(condition) { // condition for your game to keep running
          // Start 
          ball.Move(vector(...)) // vector of change
          for (Entity* block : blocks)
          {
                if (collisionDetection(ball, block))
                {
                   ball.Move(vector(...)) // vector of opposite direction to flee the collision
                }
          } 
       }
    }
```

For further inspiration:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333350/moving-point-along-the-vector